# prisma2: how to fetch nested fields?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

In prisma 1 I have used fragment to fetch the nested fields.

For example:

```
const mutations = {
  async createPost(_, args, ctx) {
    const user = await loginChecker(ctx);
    const post = await prisma.post
      .create({
        data: {
          author: {
            connect: {
              id: user.id,
            },
          },
          title: args.title,
          body: args.body,
          published: args.published,
        },
      })
      .$fragment(fragment);

    return post;
  },
};
```

but seems like in prisma2 it is not supported. because by running this on playground,

```
mutation CREATEPOST {
  createPost(
    title: "How to sleep?"
    body: "Eat, sleep, repaet"
    published: true
  ) {
    title
    body
    published
    author {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting,

```
"prisma.post.create(...).$fragment is not a function",
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [include option](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#include) is used to eagerly load relations in Prisma.

Example from docs:

```
const result = await prisma.user.findOne({
  where: { id: 1 },
  include: { posts: true },
})
```

Assuming a user table with a one-to-many posts relation, this will return back the user object with the posts field as well.

Prisma also supports nesting as well, for example:

```
const result = await prisma.user.findOne({
  where: { id: 1 },
  include: {
    posts: {
      include: {
        author: true,
      }
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: suppose I include {post and author} in createComment resolver.

when running this from playground:

```mutation CREATECOMMENT {
  createComment(text: "yep, very bad post dude", postId: 4) {
    id
    text
    post {
      id
      title 
     author: {id}


    }
    author {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

here how can I get posts {author:id} ?

Comment: So that has more to do with how your schema is defined than prisma itself. Assuming createComment returns a `Comment`, the `Comment` type needs to have `post` as a queryable field. And the `Post` type needs to have `author` as a queryable field.

Comment: you can see from my data model: https://gist.github.com/ashiqdev/17d96ac1db30c35ef8e7622992cab035

comment has relation with post and post has relation with author.

but, when created a comment I included { author: true, post: true,}. 
so, I got post and authors direct queries. but when I try to get post {author {id}}
I can't get it. In prisma1 by using fragment I used to got it.

Comment: The prisma client supports nesting includes as well `.findOne({ include: { post: { include: { 
author: true } } } })`

Comment: with nested includes, can i also add where parts so to only get those total records including all the hierarchy where a specific element deep in the tree has a specific value?